# How do I exclude specific directories from a recursive copy in a Windows batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm writing a shell script to backup the contents of the current directory to a timestamped subdirectory, `./STATES/$DATE`. Obviously I do not want to `STATES` directory itself to be re-copied each time I backup the folder, so I need to somehow exclude it from the copy.

Here's an untested shell script showing how I'd approach this on *nix:

```
ID="$(date +%Y%b%d%H%M%S)"
COMMITABLE="$(ls | egrep --invert-match ^STATES\$)"
STATE_PATH="$(pwd)/STATES/$ID"
mkdir --parents "$STATE_PATH"
cp $COMMITABLE "$STATE_PATH"
ln -s "$STATE_PATH" PARENT
```

How could I achieve this in a batch file?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to roll your own version control. Have you considered using something like mercurial instead?

Comment: It's for a system where I can't run anything except for shell scripts. Hg's good, but unfortunately it's not a choice here. :(

Comment: Hm, wasn't git just a bunch of shell scripts a while ago? :-þ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xcopy`'s `/exclude:$FILE` option can be used to specify a file containing filenames to be ignored. A friend of mine converted the script to batch like this:

```
@echo off
set thedate=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,4%
md %thedate%
echo STATES > excludefile.txt
echo excludefile.txt >> excludefile.txt
xcopy <root folder of directory structure> %thedate% /e /i /exclude:excludefile.txt
del excludefile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. This is from my own scripts:

```
set now=%date:~-4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%

rem Before 10:00 o'clock a space is used, this makes it a zero.
set now=%now: =0%

xcopy . copydir-%now% /i
```

One word of warning: this uses the US date format. For matching a different format you will have to change it. As I work with Dutch and US systems I personally use this code:

```
rem US date versus Dutch: test 5th char is /
if "%date:~-5,1%"=="/" (
   rem Date format is mm/dd/yyyy
   set now=%date:~-4%-%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
) else (
   rem Date format is dd-mm-yyyy
   set now=%date:~-4%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-10,2%-%time:~0,2%-%time:~3,2%-%time:~6,2%
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that end up copying all of the previous copydirs into the new one, 'causing the directory size to blow up?

Comment: No it will not as I did not specify /s so no sub-directories are copied. I usually do make a copy with sub-directories but then not to a sub-directory of the current directory. Use xcopy /? to find out about the /EXCLUDE option if that is what you want.